# IIS failing to serve MP4 other than to a desktop browser

Tags: iis, video, html5

I'm using the HTML5 video tag as follows:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <video>
            <source src="https://192.168.0.101/bunny.mp4" type='video/mp4' /> 
        </video>
    </body>
</html>
```

I've got an IIS mime-type for .mp4 set up as `video/mpeg`, and I'm serving this over https. The video plays fine while using firefox on a desktop, but when I try on a mobile device, the page loads but the video does not. As a quick test I've installed xampp and put the same html and mp4 file in the htdocs directory and it served it up no problem.

I've searched high and low, but beyond adding in a mime-type for IIS, I can not find any other suggestions why this may not be working.

Comment: Most likely the problem is not in IIS configuration but related to HTML5 support on mobile deviced. Could you specify the mobile devices used, including OS version?

Comment: If it was the HTML5 support, then serving the exact same document and file through apache wouldn't work, but as it does it points to something in IIS.

Comment: Then, could you provide full reply headers of both IIS and Apache. Let's compare them and see whether we can find differences that may affect the outcome.

Comment: Sorted! It was indeed the mime-type, I had set the mime-type for the server in IIS, however for reasons unknown the site had not inherited it. Thanks for point me in the direction of the reply headers, hadn't even considered that! If you could post an answer to the effect of checking the mime-types I'll be happy to accept.